# How is it possible to call a class method on a property of instance of that class?

Tags: javascript

I have been watching a tutorial about binary search tree and I just dont understand 1 thing (thats actually just about javasript).

Insight my class method, I recursively call that same method ON A PROPERTY OF THAT CLASS.

```
this.left.insert(data)
```

- How is that possible? That property is not an object /instance holding that method so I can use the dot syntax and call it on it. Could someone please explain this to me as I have never seen something like this before.
- Also, is it correct to assume, that after this.left will 'be' this.data in the new method call?

The code:

```
class Node {
 constructor(data) {
   this.data: data;
   this.left: null;
   this.right: null;
 }
 insert(data) {
   if (data < this.data && this.left) {
     this.left.insert(data)
   } else if (data > this.data) {
     this.left = new Node(data)
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: `this.left = new Node` - if `left` exists it's an instance of `Node`, so it's an object, so it has properties and methods you can call.

Comment: The `.left` property points to the memory location of the other `Node` object. `this.left` is a reference to that second Node instance; the other Node isn't "inside" the current Node.

Comment: "*That property is not an object/instance holding that method*" - yes it is.

Comment: Okay so I was trying to understand why is this.left an instance of node and not just a property of an instance of node. Is it correct that since at some point this.left must be not existent (set to null), I will go into the else condition and setting this.left to new Node. Thats why its an object like you say. If i didnt assign null to this.left, but lefts say I could assign a string to it when creating new instance of node, I COULD not call that method?! Also, if this.left is an instance holding the method and properties, it is also holding this.left / as the property?

Comment: Yes, if you assigned something else to `this.left`, like a string, then you couldn't do `this.left.insert()`. I'm not sure what the last sentence is asking really; I guess you're asking whether `this.left.left.left.left.insert()` is possible? Yes, it is.